# Match any of chars in string

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I am trying to match `ishares` where it is very inconsistently written.

`ish...s` is always there but any of `a` `r` `e` are not necessarily.
How can I write a regex in Redshift to capture all cases: `ishares`, `ishrs`, `ishs`?

Note: there is usually more data following like `ishares msci eafe`, `ishs jp morgan`, etc.

Currently I have `select sum(positions) as aum from table where name like 'ishares%' or name like 'ishrs%' or name like 'ishs'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`regexp_instr`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_INSTR.html) like this:

```
regexp_instr(name,'^isha?r?e?s$') > 0
```

The `^` and `$` are end of string anchors meaning nothing should precede or follow the match. The `?` makes  the preceding character optional.

Comment: Putting his in the where statement returns null. Putting it without >0 in the select returns 0 everywhere. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah I replaced the $ with * and that was it! BUT, the total(amount) is now lower then with the like statement before

Comment: That is logical: the `like` statements you listed would also accept when other characters followed after the final `s` in the pattern.